# Pentaho - Set values and copy to result

Tags: pentaho

That's really weird question but I am a bit confused and don;t know how to handle with that "issue".
I'm trying to create and set some field values in Pentaho transformation.
For example:
1 ktr : I want to create some variable/field etc with values: 01,02,03,04,05 and 06
2 ktr: I want to use that values in call db procedure step.

What I was trying to do was use set variables/set field value to a constant etc -> copy rows to result
And in second ktr Get rows from Result -> Call db Procedure..

When as input I have text file then it works fine, but I don't want to do smth like that. I would like to define values inside Pentaho ktr.
How to do that...?

Comment: Have you tried defining the variables as parameters in a job, then do `set variables` at the job level, then pass as arguments to the second ktr?

Comment: Hey, I used "Generate rows" step : )